# WCF URI only works on localhost

Tags: c#, wcf

After creating a service host, I am not able to open page "http://myuri:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service" when I use internet explorer.

```
  Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://myuri:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service");

  // Step 2 of the hosting procedure: Create ServiceHost
  ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);
  // rest of the below code is from calculator MSDN sample
```

It only works if I use localhost instead of "myuri". Can someone please tell what else is required?

EDIT: myri is actually my PC name. I tried using IP adress for my PC also. Internet explorer is able to open up the URL from my box, but it fails when I open the URL from other box (eg., the URL I am trying to open is http://111.251.164.20:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eh... `myuri` is just an example, a placeholder. Not something you should use literally.

Comment: i can't place an arbitrary string, only localhost works. is it possible to place an arbitrary string?

Comment: @quantcoder: Take your pick between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. Really, you should read up a little on how servers (in general, not WCF specifically) accept connections. You cannot create a socket bound to an IP address other than yours, or a hostname other than yours.

Comment: no, it must at least be in your hosts file or be a valid dns record actually pointing to an interface on the machine as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use myuri you need to add a record to your hosts.ini file.

Like: 127.0.0.1 myuri localhost